# PHP & MySQL performance - One big query vs. multiple small

Tags: php, mysql, performance

For an MySQL table I am using the InnoDB engine and the structure of my tables looks like this:

**Table user**

```
 id |  username  |  etc...
----|------------|--------
  1 | bruce      | ...
  2 | clark      | ...
  3 | tony       | ...
```

**Table user-emails**

```
 id |  person_id  |  email
----|-------------|---------
  1 |          1  | bruce@wayne-ent.com
  2 |          1  | ceo@wayne-ent.com
  3 |          2  | clark.k@daily-planet.com
```

To fetch data from the database I've written a tiny framework. E.g. on `__construct($id)` it checks if there is a person with the given id, if yes it creates the corresponding model and saves only the field `id` to an array. During runtime, if I need another field from the model it fetches only the value from the database, saves it to the array and returns it. E.g. same with the field `emails` for that my code accesses the table `user-emails` and get all the emails for the corresponding user.

For small models this works alright, but now I am working on another project where I have to fetch a lot of data at once for a list and that takes some time. Also I know that many connections to MySQL and many queries are quite stressful for the server, so..

**My question now is:** Should I fetch all data at once (with left joins etc.) while constructing the model and save the fields as an array or should I use some other method?

Comment: ... depends. Generally speaking using many simple queries will perform better than using one complicated one; but that depends on *how* complicated it is and how your indexes are set up.

Comment: You should just measure the performance and see if there is a problem.

Comment: @CD001 that comment actually surprises me, the amount that people try and cram as many SQL queries into one big query made me think fewer larger queries was generally speaking more efficient.....I guess I shouldn't follow the crowd..... `:-D`

Comment: @CD001 yep, same for me, quite surprising... well the main table has 25 fields, and then there are 11 of those multi-row tables. 
Performance wise - to load 60 of those rows it takes on my laptop (via xampp) around 10 seconds.

Comment: @Martin ... I've fallen into that trap before ;) I needed to run some big loops (on a dev box) and make liberal use of `EXPLAIN` before I realised that bigger isn't always better!

Comment: @CD001 set your comments as an answer and I'd happy reference it when I see people trying to blend multiple SQLs into one single query simply for a perceived efficiency. Although I've often seen it,  I've never bothered to test and `EXPLAIN` it in my own work....

Comment: @Martin - just about to hop in the car so that might be tricky ;) I'm sure there's a detailed post on either the DBAs or Server Admins Stack Exchange somewhere from when I last looked into it...

Comment: @CD001 since I am using extremely simple small queries, like `SELECT field1, field2, field3 FROM table WHERE person_id = $id` that should be an issue and I should check my code performance drops?

Comment: @CD001 with the coming of AI controlled cars, soon we can SO while we drive!!!

Comment: 10 second queries sounds like a very long time.

Comment: @CD001 It depends on the query and the environment. If the application and database run on different servers, the communication overhead of lots of queries can be significant.

Comment: @Barmar I feel that raises an interesting point as to the statistics of servers who run "localhost" SQL, versus dedicated SQL servers for larger organisations. I have an impression that short of *Large* organisations, servers these days most often run Browser Output as well as Data Storage all together.... an interesting topic I know nothing about (just impressions)

Comment: That framework cannot scale -- If there is "too much" data, you will run out of RAM.

Comment: @Barmar - quite true, but if you're on something like AWS then the latency between the application server and the database server is surprisingly small; but yeah, there are lots of factors to consider - the overhead in connecting to the db server, how well indexed the tables are and how you use those indexes in the query (especially if you're ordering the result), sub-queries vs joins (in *some* instances I've found sub-queries are faster), whether you're using database caching... I think we agree that *"depends"* is the most accurate answer ;)

Comment: @CD001 We have our servers in lots of different datacenters. Some are in the same datacenter as the database, some are not, so our latency is very variable. We use AWS, SoftLayer, Rackspace, and other services. It's probably much more complicated than most people here have to deal with, but we end up being very sensitive to network latency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do people insist on referring to the entities and domain objects as "models".

Unless your entities are extremely large, I would populate the entire entity, when you need it. And, if "email list" is part of that entity, I would populate that too.

As I see it, the question is more related to "what to do with tables, that are related by foreign keys".

Lets say you have `Users` and `Articles` tables, where each article has a specific owner associate by `user_id` foreign key. In this case, when populating the `Article` entity, I would only retrieve the `user_id` value instead of pulling in all the information about the user.

But in your example with `Users` and `UserEmails`, the emails seem to be a part of the `User` entity, and something that you would often call via `$user->getEmailList()`.

**TL;DR**

I would do this in two queries, when populating `User` entity:

1. select all you need from Users table and apply to `User` entity
2. select all user's emails from the UserEmails table and apply it to `User` entity.

**P.S**

You might want to look at [data mapper](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html) pattern for "how" part.

Comment: the example with `users` + `articles` is something different, those are basically 2 different entities. In my case all those other tables belong to the same entity and for me right now all of them appear in a list.

Comment: Did  you read the part that begun with "But in your example ..."?

Comment: yep, just now got to consider that solution. What about PHP? Wouldn't that kinda pollute the memory if I am not using some of the field of the main table?

Comment: @donnikitos you don't have to query across all fields. Additionally, again, 'is this using too much memory' and 'is this going to be fast enough' are best answered by simple measurements (which you can compare to initial estimates but the measurement is always better).

Comment: Depends on what are you retrieving.  If your user entity also always retrieves password hash, then the problems might actually be, that you need separate the "login credentials" from "user profile". And if you are using a *data mapper*, you can specify which fields you want to actually select.

Comment: **Something to consider:** "premature optimization is root of all evil". You should always make the code easy to understand and only then look at whether you need to make it faster.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you should **fetch all your fields at once**, and divide queries in a way that makes your code easier to read/manage.

When we're talking about one query or two, the difference is usually negligible unless the combined query (with `JOIN`s or whatever) is overly complex. Usually an index or two is the solution to a very slow query.

If we're talking about one vs hundreds or thousands of queries, that's when the connection/transmission overhead becomes more significant, and reducing the number of queries can make an impact.

It seems that your framework suffers from [premature optimization](http://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization). You are hyper-concerned about fetching too many fields from a row, but why? Do you have thousands of columns or something?

The time consuming part of your query is almost always the lookup, not the transmission of data. You are causing the database to do the "hard" part over and over again as you pull one field at a time.

Comment: I am just wondering how that would impact on the server. Of course I won't have thousands of columns, but somewhere around 70. And if I am loading for example 100 rows at once it would be already 7000 fields in total and this is what makes me think.

Comment: I would be far more concerned about 7000 queries to get 100 rows of data, vs 1 query to get 7000 fields. Even if every field was 20 bytes, we are still only talking about 140 KB of data.

Comment: Again, your saying it takes you 10 seconds to load 60 rows. That's insane. MySQL can query 60 rows, joined across 11 tables (each with millions of rows and 25 columns) in the blink of an eye.

Comment: Large `TEXT` and `BLOB` columns are stored in a separate area.  In _this_ case, unnecessarily including them in the `SELECT` is a performance hit.